# What benefits or powers does a cleric gain from choosing a deity?

Tags: dnd-4e, cleric, religions-and-deities

Is there any benefit from choosing a god? What are they? Do they change per level? Is it available to use at all times? Do they involve rituals? What are the prerequisites?

Comment: The benefit following a god is gaining direction in life, a philosophical mindset on which the solution to any quandry can be based, and the ability to draw strength from faith in times of trial. Those are all roleplaying benefits, though - I can't speak about the mechanical ones.

Comment: And for a third time, what books do you own?

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton I own the PHB 1, the Monster Manual and the DM Guide.... those are all xD

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In 4th ed, the only real mechanical differences you get from following a specific god are that it determines the types of Channel Divinity powers available to a Divine character, and perhaps allows some additional feats, paragon paths or backgrounds.

Also, note that a Warpriest, an Essentials cleric, gets different powers based on the type of god (domain) he follows although again, this is tied more to an ideal than a specific god.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanically there are no benefits. Gods and alignment play little to no mechanical role in D&D 4th edition.

Clerics can worship any god or none. Divine classes such as Clerics and Paladins have access to the same powers regardless of what god they worship or alignment they belong to. From a cursory inspection I cannot even find paragon paths or powers restricted to followers of specific gods: even a worshiper of the Raven Queen can use Pelor's Radiance.

Off the top of my head the only thing I can think of which actually cares about your god is artifacts, which can be aligned to specific gods and favour worshipers of their gods or members of that god's alignment.

Comment: Morninglord paragon path, and there are deity specific channel divinity feats as well. And at least one Holy Symbol is limited to followers of Pelor